# Trend of 1 feature in a regression model

Tags: regression, time-series, feature-selection

Let's say I have a regression model that is trying predict sales of a product in 1 year. I have about 10,000 data points with features like:

- sales in first 4 months
- product type
- ...

The first feature is the only time dependent one. The issue is that the trend of the sales is also important. For example, if each week product A is selling 10 units, 20 units, 30 units, ... and product B is selling 30 units, 20 units, 10 units, then they both sold the same amount, but product A is growing while product B is declining. Product A would likely sell more than product B, but this information is lost in the current model.

Is there anyway to incorporate this trend as a feature in the regression model?

Comment: How many weeks of data do you have? Maybe look into time series.

Comment: I have 16 weeks of data. I have looked into time series, but isn’t it not enough data to forecast from week 16 to week 52?

Comment: 16 weeks with weekly data is enough to start investigating time series properties like autocorrelation functions.  Why do you need weekly forecasts for all the weks 17-52 at once? 16 weeks of data is certainly not enough to investigate seasonalities and such. But simpler models cannot either! You can always include time as a predictor in a regression model, but in your case that will be extreme extrapolation.

Comment: This is just an example I made so I apologize if it is unclear, but basically a decision needs to be made at week 16 about whether to invest in the product. I want to be able to pick the ones that have the highest likelihood of success at the time.

Comment: Then maybe, if the information in data is insufficient, you must take account of any other info/guesses and maybe use a bayes approach?

Comment: yes, that could be a good solution. I will look into it. Thanks!